# abs(): Argument #1 ($num) must be of type int|float, string given in PHP 8.2

Tags: php

I have just updated my php version from 7.4 to 8.2 and i have the below error, abs(): Argument #1 ($num) must be of type int|float, string given am so sure that it has to do with phh version update as the current code running on php 7.4 still works perfectly. How can I solve this problem is there a replacement for abs() in php 8.2?

```
protected function encryptMethodLength()
    {
        $number = filter_var($this->encryptMethod, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

        return intval(abs($number));
    }/
```

/ encryptMethodLength

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is related to the response of the filter_var(), which is not cast the string to an integer if you send something like `test` as a parameter. Here you can see the error:

https://3v4l.org/PlI5c

Here you can see the problematic part, and solution will be something like this :

```php
<?php

function encryptMethodLengthSolved($encryptMethod) {
    $number = filter_var($encryptMethod, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    return abs(intval($number));
}
```

But don't forget that the function won't throw exceptions. Just cast the string to integer as `0`.

Comment: thanks for your response but while would this same code work without givingerror in php 7.4 , a little bit weired

Comment: I changes `return intval(abs($number));` this with`return abs(intval($number));`

Comment: abs will return int|float in any case you don't need to cast it with inval

Comment: The reason is abs changed with 8.0.0 version of PHP you can see the changelog on [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) page